# how to spirally traverse a matrix recursively - javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, matrix

Please look at this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hc2jcx26/

I am trying to spirally traverse a matrix `output` (any size) so that it prints each element in spiral order to `console.log` every 2 seconds:

```
var output = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6, 7]];
```

I am expecting this output:

```
0
1 //after 2 seconds delay
2 //after 2 seconds delay
3 //etc.
7
6
5
4
```

But I am not getting this with the code above. The output is all over the place and doesn't even have the right number of elements. I am using recursion to add a delay in my loop after every iteration (through `setTimeout`), but I do not think I am setting the variables correctly. But when I look at the code, it makes sense to me. What am I missing here?

Comment: is you question about timeout or how to get the spiral values from the array?

Comment: @NinaScholz its about timeout because spiral algorithm is correct (i tested it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach to your problem.

**Iterative version**

```
var matrix1 = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
], matrix2 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [10, 11, 12]
], matrix3 = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6, 7]
], matrix4 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

(function (matrix) {
    var i,
        nRows = matrix.length,
        nCols = matrix[0].length,
        rowLimit = nRows - 1,
        colLimit = nCols - 1,
        rounds = 0,
        printedElements = 0,
        nElements = nRows * nCols,
        timeoutLapse = 2000;

    function print(val) {
        printedElements += 1;
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(val);
        }, printedElements * timeoutLapse);
    }

    do {
        for (i = rounds; i <= colLimit - rounds; i += 1) {// from left to right
            print(matrix[rounds][i]);
        }

        for (i = rounds + 1; i <= rowLimit - rounds; i += 1) {// from top to bottom
            print(matrix[i][colLimit - rounds]);
        }

        for (i = colLimit - rounds - 1; i >= rounds; i -= 1) {// from right to left
            print(matrix[rowLimit - rounds][i]);
        }

        for (i = rowLimit - rounds - 1; i >= rounds + 1; i -= 1) {// from bottom to top
            print(matrix[i][rounds]);
        }
        rounds += 1;
    } while (printedElements < nElements);

})(matrix4);
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pb7h8h5w/) (you'll have to open the console in order to see the results).

**Recursive version**

```
var matrix1 = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
], matrix2 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [10, 11, 12]
], matrix3 = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6, 7]
], matrix4 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

(function(matrix){
    var printedElements = 0,
        timeoutLapse = 1000;

    function print(val) {
        printedElements += 1;
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(val);
        }, printedElements * timeoutLapse);
    }

    function printArray(arr) {
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            print(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    // Recursive algorithm, consumes the matrix.
    function printMatrix(matrix, direction) {
        var dir = direction % 4,
            rowLimit = matrix.length - 1,
            i;

        if (dir === 0) {// from left to right
            printArray(matrix.shift());
        } else if (dir === 1) {// from top to bottom
            for(i = 0; i <= rowLimit; i++) {
                print(matrix[i].pop());
            }
        } else if (dir === 2) {// from right to left
            printArray(matrix.pop().reverse());
        } else {// from bottom to top
            for(i = rowLimit; i >= 0; i--) {
                print(matrix[i].shift());
            }
        }

        if (matrix.length) {// Guard
            printMatrix(matrix, direction + 1);
        }
    }

    // Initial call.
    printMatrix(matrix, 0);
})(matrix4);
```

I added some examples in order to test it. I just print out elements of the matrix every two seconds following the spiral pattern.

As you can see, the recursive version is more declarative though it empties the matrix completely. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5vzqpdn/)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer to add the recursive version (just for fun). Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
var output = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6, 7]];

    var columns = output[0].length;
    var row;

    function spiralOrderRecursive (matrix, rowIndex) {
      rowIndex = rowIndex || 0;
      if (matrix.length) {
        row = rowIndex % 2 ? matrix[0].reverse() : matrix[0];
        row.forEach(function (item, index) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(item);
          }, (rowIndex * columns + index) * 2000);
        });
        spiralOrderRecursive (matrix.slice(1), ++rowIndex);
      }
    }
spiralOrderRecursive(output);
```

also NON RECURSIVE

```js
var output = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 5],
                  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                  [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                  [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]];;
var columns = output[0].length;

function spiralOrder(output) {
      output.forEach(function (row, rowIndex) {
        row = rowIndex % 2 ? row.reverse() : row;
        row.forEach(function (item, index) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(item);
          }, (rowIndex * columns + index) * 2000);
        });
      });
    }
spiralOrder(output);
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for matrix that is two rows (4x2). How would I modify the non-recursive solution so it goes thru the spiral for matrices of all sizes?

Comment: it can take any size of matrix, for example I changed output in my previous answer, so it is now 5x4 matrix

Comment: The output should be 0,1,2,3,5,10,15,20,19,18,17,16,11,6,7,8,9,14,13,12 in which it forms a spiral traversal. Currently, it seems to be traversing it snake-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code for what you want to do

```
spiral_print(matrix)
{ 
 If the matrix has one row
   print the row and go to new line
 else if the matrix has two rows
  print the first row and go to new line
  sleep(2)
  print the second row in reverse order and go to new line
 else
  print the first row and go to new line
  sleep(2)
  print the second row in reverse order and go to new line
  sleep(2)      
  spiral_print(matrix.slice(2))
}
```

Comment: I am not only limiting myself to a matrix with two rows. I need this function to work even if it has 5 rows.

Comment: The case when a matrix has greater than two rows will be accounted for in  "else
  print the first row
  print the second row in reverse order
  spiral_print(matrix.slice(2))
}"

Answer (score 0):

**Using JS**

**UPDATE: Leveraging @acontell's print function**

```
function spiral(matrix) {
    if (matrix.length <= 0) {
        return
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
        print(matrix[0][i])
    }

    //Get last col
    for (var i = 1; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        print(matrix[i][matrix[0].length - 1])
    }

    //Get last row
    for (var i = matrix[0].length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        print(matrix[matrix.length-1][i])
    }

    //Get first column
    for (var i = matrix.length - 2; i > 0; i--) {
        print(matrix[i][0])
    }
    matrix = matrix.slice(1, -1)
    for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        matrix[i] = matrix[i].slice(1, -1)
    }
    spiral(matrix)
}           
function print(val) {
    printedElements += 1;
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(val);
    }, printedElements * 2000);
}
var printedElements = 0
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
            [5, 6, 7, 8],
            [9, 10, 11, 12],
            [13, 14, 15, 16]]
matrix1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 31],
            [5, 6, 7, 8, 32],
            [9, 10, 11, 12, 33],
            [13, 14, 15, 16, 34],
            [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]]
spiral(matrix1)
```

**Using Python**
Note: It's much easier with numpy

```
def spiral(matrix):
    if len(matrix) <= 0:
        return
    for v in matrix[0]:
        print(v)
    last_col = [matrix[i][len(matrix[0]) - 1] for i in range(1,len(matrix))]
    for v in last_col:
        print(v)
    last_row = reversed(matrix[len(matrix)-1][0:-1])
    for v in last_row:
        print(v)
    first_col = [matrix[i][0] for i in range (1, len(matrix) - 1)]
    first_col = reversed(first_col)
    for v in first_col:
        print(v)
    matrix = matrix[1:len(matrix) - 1]
    matrix = [m[1:len(matrix[0]) - 1] for m in matrix]
    spiral(matrix)
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
            [5, 6, 7, 8],
            [9, 10, 11, 12],
            [13, 14, 15, 16]]
matrix1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 31],
            [5, 6, 7, 8, 32],
            [9, 10, 11, 12, 33],
            [13, 14, 15, 16, 34],
            [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]]

spiral(matrix1)
```

**UPDATE: With numpy**

```
import numpy as np

def spiral(matrix):
    if len(matrix) <= 0:
        return
    for v in matrix[0]:
        print(v)
    last_col = matrix[1:, -1]
    for v in last_col:
        print(v)
    last_row = reversed(matrix[-1, :-1])
    for v in last_row:
        print(v)
    first_col = reversed(matrix[1:-1, 0])
    for v in first_col:
        print(v)
    matrix = matrix[1:-1, 1:-1]
    spiral(matrix)
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
            [5, 6, 7, 8],
            [9, 10, 11, 12],
            [13, 14, 15, 16]]
matrix1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 31],
            [5, 6, 7, 8, 32],
            [9, 10, 11, 12, 33],
            [13, 14, 15, 16, 34],
            [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]]
matrix2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 31],
            [5, 6, 7, 8, 32],
            [9, 10, 11, 12, 33],
            [13, 14, 15, 16, 34],
            [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]])


spiral(matrix2)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your JS function is clear and concise. How would I implement a delay after every iteration however? Say, after every element printed, it needs to wait 2 seconds before it prints again?

Comment: `setTimeout(function()
    {
       print(v)
    }, 2000);`. Do this for all print statements. You can make a separate print function if you'd like and call that instead of the default print function.

Comment: Updated code with @acontell's print function for the delay